# Postgres COPY and SQL commands in the same script

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL script -

```
--This is a function 
SELECT * FROM import ('test');

TRUNCATE table some_table;

cat <<SQL
\COPY (
SELECT * from large_query
)
TO '/tmp/dash.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
SQL
;
```

I am getting a parse error when I run this script like this -

`psql -h host -p port -U user db -f my_file.sql`

Can regular SQL statements not be combined with the `\COPY` command?

Comment: `\copy` must stay on a single line.

Comment: Per docs [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html): 'Another way to obtain the same result as \copy ... to is to use the SQL COPY ... TO STDOUT command and terminate it with \g filename or \g |program. Unlike \copy, this method allows the command to span multiple lines; also, variable interpolation and backquote expansion can be used.'